# The spectral radius of the matrix $A$ is less than or equal any natural norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Show that the spectral radius of the matrix A is less than or equal
any natural norm, i.e:

$$\rho(A) \leq ||A||=\max_{||x||=1}{||Ax||}$$

where $\rho(A)=\max\{|\lambda|:\lambda \text{ is a eigenvalue of $A$}\}$.

I'm a little confused with this, because I'm not sure about the definition of natural norm of $A$. If $\rho(A)=\lambda^*$ and $u$ is such that $||u||=1$, then:
\begin{align*}
||A||&\geq ||Au||\\
&=||\lambda^* u||\\
&=|\lambda^*| 
\end{align*}
Is this ok?

Thanks.

Comment: Just assume $\rho(A) = |\lambda^\ast|$ instead of $\rho(A) =  \lambda^\ast $ and your reasoning becomes correct.

Comment: (1) you are mixing $u$ and $x$ when you say " $x$ is such that $||u||=1$". (2) why $||Au||=||\lambda u||$?

Comment: (1) Yes, thanks, I edited my question. (2) Do you mean $\lambda^*$? because $\lambda^*$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: If $A$ is not symmetric, then you may not be able to find a unit eigenvector.

Comment: Why would you not be able to find a unit eigenvector? If $Au = \lambda u$, then we can multiply both sides by $\frac {1}{||u||}$, we get $A \frac {u}{||u||_1} = \lambda \frac {u}{||u||_1}$, or in other words $Av = \lambda v$ where $||v||_1 = 1$. I don't see any place where we needed that $A$ is symmetric.