# Simple estimator for biggest singular value

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, singular-values

I was reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.06394.pdf) where they used $\sqrt{\|A\|_\infty \|A\|_1 }$ as an estimate of the biggest singular value $\sigma_{max}(A)$ of a non-singular matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

However, this claim is not justified, and I cannot understand the reasoning behind it.

Recall that $\|A\|_{\infty}$ is defined as $\text{max}_{1 \leq i \leq n} \sum_j^{n} |a_{ij}|$
while $\|A\|_{1}$ is defined as $\text{max}_{1 \leq j\leq n} \sum_i^{n} |a_{ij}|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In algorithm 2, $\sigma_\max$ is an upperbound for the singular value.

To obtain an upper bound for the singular values:

$$\rho(A^TA)\le \|A^TA\|_1=\|A^T\|_1\|A\|_1 = \|A\|_\infty \|A\|_1$$

Comment: Very nice answer Siong! For justifying the first inequality, can we just say: let $\lambda$ be the largest (in magnitude) eigenvalue of a matrix $B$, and let $v$ be corresponding eigenvector with $||v||_1 = 1$. Then $$|\lambda| = ||\lambda v||_1 = ||Bv||_1 \le ||B||_1 ||v||_1 = ||B||_1$$If yes, it looks like we can replace the $1$ norm with any matrix norm induced by a vector norm, right?

Comment: Related:[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/494696/306553)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. I see that my proof is essentially correct, but I needed to specify that $B$ is square. There is a comment there saying that if $B$ is not symmetric, you may not be able to find a unit eigenvector. But I think that's wrong.

Comment: that comment is puzzling to me too.